# Building credit history as a young foreigner

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit-history

I moved to the US for college, and have decided to stay in the Bay Area.

As soon as I found my first internship, I applied for a credit card. Currently, I have 3 credit cards, and the oldest card is 3 years, giving me a credit score of 760 but thin credit history. What's my next best move for improving my credit history/score? Note that I am willing to take a few hits now to prepare myself for a bigger loan in 5 years.

- I have no student loans.
- I keep my credit utilization on my cards at around 10%.
- I rent an apartment.
- I bought a cheap, used car, which I paid for in cash.

Comment: You've got a great score. I'd suggest you continue doing exactly what you have been doing.

Comment: Being a foreigner is entirely irrelevant to the question. There's no "citizenship" points for the credit score.

Comment: @littleadv: Maybe, but the questioner doesn't necessarily know that.  Given that we usually have to ask people to *add* relevant info to the question, I don't see anything wrong with the person including that info in the (reasonable) belief it might be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the comment, 760 is a good score. The average score is less than 700 and average score for your age group is even lower.  (Source: https://www.creditkarma.com/trends/age)

Just keep paying your credit card bills on time.

You could also ask for increases in your credit limits on your existing credit cards, which may increase your score, but could decrease it in the short term depending on how your credit card company looks at your credit history in the process.  (Source: http://money.usnews.com/money/blogs/my-money/2014/06/27/3-ways-to-increase-your-credit-card-spending-limit)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with wrschneider99. Also, since it's a "credit report" it helps to have a history of credit. My wife has been in the U.S. for 14 years and now has a higher credit score than me, a U.S. citizen. When we leased a car we put it in her name. When we took out a mortgage it's under both our names.

Comment: Welcome to [Money.SE]!  Please be sure to read the Help section, especially [How to write good answers](http://money.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).  In this case you might want to elaborate more on the part of your response that actually addresses the OP's question -- about having a history of credit.  How does one build a history of credit?  Why is the history more/less important than other aspects of the credit score?